# Recycler View Add Remove Item Animations not showing in swapCursor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursor

How to implement Recycler View Default Item Add/Remove Animations in swapCursor function. notifyDataSetChanged() won't show any animations.

```
public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        mCursor = newCursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set the following in activity,

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

And in adapter, write

```
 setHasStableIds(true); //in constructor 
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return cameraImageArrayList.get(position).hashCode(); //Any unique id
    }
```

Comment: Yes , I am trying this.. Will let you know whether it works.. See second answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300811/recyclerview-adapter-notifydatasetchanged-stops-fancy-animation

Comment: Yes.. My solution is the same. I have tried and it worked for me!